# Bottom half of vertical monitor is blank after updating video drivers

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, display

*I've edited the title of this question, because one answer below created a new problem in the process of solving the first problem.*

Just this morning I downloaded the latest Kernel (3.19.0-30).  When I restarted and booted into it, the screen goes blank just before the login screen would have come up.  I can still enter my password, and hit enter.  The fan spins.  I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to get a terminal, do `sudo reboot`, enter my password, and the computer reboots.  So the system is running, but no display.

I reboot into the oldest one that I have (3.19.0-25).  Same problem.

I reboot into the next one (3.19.0-26).  It works!

Why?  What is going on here?  And how to I make it so that I can boot into the newest kernel without this problem?

Edit as per comment:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 062b
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 062b
```

**Edit**:  When I follow the answer of @pilot6 below, I can indeed boot into the most recent kernel that I have.  But now I have a problem with my external monitor the bottom half of the external monitor (which is turned vertical) is chopped off!  (Note that the tiled cookie monster wallpaper is just there for visibility -- I normally just use a black background :)

However, when I take a screenshot, the screenshot shows the whole of the vertical monitor, rather than just the top half.  Below are screenshots and camera pictures.

I get the same problem when I boot into both cinnamon and unity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: The problem must be with video driver installed without dkms.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can switch to Intel that you used before.

Comment: And please do not change your question this way. You need to ask another question if you change the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you have quite new GPU hardware use the stable NVIDIA drivers from the long-lived branch.

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting 840M from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

In case you have had any NVIDIA drivers installed before and to avoid possible conflicts, it is a very good idea to **first uninstall every NVIDIA related software** you have **installed before**.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Note: When you have had installed **bumblebee** before, this software **must be removed** as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Could you please tell me why I would ever want to switch between NVIDIA and Intel?  And what is bumblebee?

Comment: @generic_user : You have integrated intel and dedicated NVIDIA graphics, so when you want to use intel choose intel, when you want to use NVIDIA switch to NVIDIA. Bumblebee is an older solution to switch ... nvidia-prime is somewhat a better, newer and more consequent "replacement". :)

Comment: OK cool, but what is a hypothetical situation when someone would want to use Intel and not NVIDIA, or vice versa?

Comment: @generic_user : intel for standard tasks (in cases when you mostly use applications like office suites) and NVIDIA for things like gaming (when graphics "power" is needed) ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Install the proprietary nvidia drivers this way:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

You can switch to Intel adapter by running:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

That should fix the external adapter issue after reboot.

Comment: I tried this and I can now boot into my current kernel, but doing so caused a different problem!  See above.

Comment: How do I undo your advice and go back to how it was before??

Comment: Run the second command. You do not need to undo anything.